# how can i do lot of operation on mongodb document?

Tags: mongodb, tornado

here is my schema:

```
"_id" : "tofla@darhoum.dz"

"modif" : 1

"prs" :
{
"pass" : "sdfdsf"
}

"reset" :
[
{
"code" : "1680"
"timr" : "AQQOAAMGCQMcBgodAAYYAgIMDAkLBAEeAAcNAAEG"
}
]
```

i want to execute lot of operation **IN THE SAME LINE OF CODE**

```
yield tornado.gen.Task(db.users.update, {"_id":email}, {"$set":{"prs.pass":password}}, {"$inc":{"modif":1}}, {"$pop":{"reset":1}})
```

and i got this error:

```
assert isinstance(upsert, bool), "upsert must be an instance of bool"
AssertionError: upsert must be an instance of bool
```

but when i split the operation into THREE it works,

```
yield tornado.gen.Task(db.users.update, {"_id":email}, {"$set":{"prs.pass":password}})
yield tornado.gen.Task(db.users.update, {"_id":email}, {"$pop":{"reset":1}})
yield tornado.gen.Task(db.users.update, {"_id":email}, {"$inc":{"modif":1}})
```

i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823140/multiple-mongo-update-operator-in-a-single-statement) but thought that it is not the same thing in asynchronous calls, is this mongodb lock?

Update: tried this and worked:

```
yield [tornado.gen.Task(db.users.update, {"_id":email}, {"$set":{"prs.pass":password}}),
      tornado.gen.Task(db.users.update, {"_id": email}, {"$pop":{"reset":1}}),
      tornado.gen.Task(db.users.update, {"_id":email}, {"$inc":{"modif":1}})]
```

but isent dangerous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass multiple operators in the `dict` provided to the `document` argument of update:

```
yield tornado.gen.Task(db.users.update, {"_id":email}, {"$set":{"prs.pass":password}, "$inc":{"modif":1}, "$pop":{"reset":1}})
```