# MongoDB schema structure and queries

Tags: mongodb, schema, meteor

I am using the meteor implementation of mongoDB and currently have a schema structured as such:

```
{
 photoalbum 1:
    {
     description: album,
     title: xyz,
     photos:
        {
         photo 1:
            {
             description: photo,
             photodata:
                {
                 title:xyz,
                 url:...,
                 tags:xyz
                }
            },
         photo 2:
            {....},
         photo 3:
            {....},
        }
    },
 photoalbum 2:
    {
     description: album,
     title: xyz,
     photos:
        {
         photo 1:
            {....},
         photo 2:
            {....},
         photo 3:
            {....},        
        }
    }
}
```

What I am effectively trying to do is to nest an array / object of photos inside their parent albums. My logic for doing this is that I'd like to be able to return all photos from a particular set and it seems intuitive to keep related photos nested together.

My question boils down to:

1) Is this schema design OK - or is it getting too nested and complex? For example, should I just leave the photos mixed in with the the sets in the top level of the collection?

2) How do I structure the database.find() operation to return only photos that belong to a certain set? I thought I'd be able to search for a particular type of item (e.g. {description:"photo"} within a certain parent level (e.g. {description:"album"} but I haven't figured out how this would actually work. Do I have to embed an album identifier in each photo and then query photos that match that identifier?

3) When is it better to use an array vs. an object - for example, my photolist is current an object, should this rather be an array?

Thanks.

Comment: Your photoalbums and photos should probably be in an array.  One issue that you may run into is properly querying for data.  Querying on an array element isn't hard, but it does require you to change your queries a bit.

Comment: Can you give a better/clear example of item 2 (and drop a comment with the text @vinipsmaker, then I'll be notified and I'll be able to finish my answer)?

Comment: @vinipsmaker - I have been trying to query by using something along the lines of the following collectionName.find({setID:"number"}) ... I have been trying to return the set results to a variable, and then to use dot notation to retrieve the data of the nested photos. It isn't working yet and I still have more investigating to do... Ideally I would like to return a particular set's photo array to an object, and then iterate through them using #each in the handlebars template. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1)

> Is this schema design OK - or is it getting too nested and complex?

This design requires you to know the photos key in advance, if you plan to do any operation to these keys. If this is okay to you, this design might work.

Other options would be:

- Use an array of photos instead of an object photos.
- Use a separate collection instead of embeding.

Indeed, schema design depends on your data, but, also important is **what** you plan to do with that data. The *what* is also important to the schema design.

> For example, should I just leave the photos mixed in with the the sets in the top level of the collection?

Don't.

## 2)

> How do I structure the database.find() operation to return only photos that belong to a certain set? I thought I'd be able to search for a particular type of item (e.g. {description:"photo"} within a certain parent level (e.g. {description:"album"} but I haven't figured out how this would actually work. Do I have to embed an album identifier in each photo and then query photos that match that identifier?

### If you use an embeded document/array

Your query might look like this:

```js
db.album.find({_id: 0/*album id*/})
```

And if you use arrays instead of objects, you can even query based on the photo's fields (you can read more about this [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/#array) and [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/#id3)):

```js
db.album.find({_id: 0/*album id*/, "photos.description": "hi there"})
```

### If you se a separate collection for photos

You need to put the info about the containing album somewhere. If you put this info in the album collection, you'll need two queries. But, if you put this info in the photos collection, your query might look like:

```js
db.photos.find({parentAlbum: 0/*album id*/})
```

## 3)

> When is it better to use an array vs. an object - for example, my photolist is current an object, should this rather be an array?

If you can use an array without any problems, I'd recommend you that way, because you'll have richer expressiveness.

It might be problematic if you need a reference to an individual element of the array ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595195/is-it-possible-to-utilize-addtoset-multiple-times-in-the-same-update/16620099)).

## PS.:

This is a confusing question. I'm not sure if I was able to answer what you asked for.