# Mongodb multiple operators

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mlab

Is there a way to write this part better?

```
'update': function (req, res) {
    var item = req.body.item;
    var tags = [];
    tag.find(function (err, _tags) {
        tags = _tags;
        post.update({ '_id': item._id }, { $set: { Text: item.Text } }, function (e1, r1) {
            post.update({ '_id': item._id }, { $pullAll: { Tags: tags } }, function (e2, r2) { 
                post.update({ '_id': item._id }, { $pushAll: { Tags: item.Tags } }, function (e3, r3) {
                    if (r3 === 1) {
                        res.json(true);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

`Post` has array of tags, and i want to update tags, i get all tags, and `$pullAll` them to empty the array of item tags, then `$pushAll` to fill again, i don't want to append new tags, because it's an update method, above code works as expected, but guess it's a bit incorrect

Comment: Wouldn't a single `{ $set: { Text: item.Text, Tags: item.Tags } }` do the same thing?

Comment: you are right, answer and i will mark, i think i asked not correct way, can you tell how to make multiple operators in 1 line or i should make new question?

Comment: See this other post for your follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823140/multiple-mongo-update-operator-in-a-single-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to replace the existing `Tags` with the new set, you can simplify that to:

```
'update': function (req, res) {
    var item = req.body.item;
    post.update({ '_id': item._id },
        { $set: { Text: item.Text, Tags: item.Tags } },
        function (e1, r1) {
            if (r1 === 1) {
                res.json(true);
            }
        }
    );
}
```