# mongodb - how to build a multi operator update statement with java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

How do I execute different updates on different fields of a single document as a single operation using java driver?
Suppose I have a document like this

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("1234567890")
   ...
   elements: String[],
   last_user: String,
   ...
}
```

and I want to add a string to the `elements` array and update `last_user`. I can do it as

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Updates.*;

...

Bson filter = eq(DBCollection.ID_FIELD_NAME, new ObjectId("1234567890"));
Bson addElement = push("elements", "a new string");
Bson updateLastUser = set("last_user", "last user name");

mycollection.updateOne(filter, addElement);
mycollection.updateOne(filter, updateLastUser);
```

it works but those are two separate operations, and I don't actually like it at all.

I saw [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823140/multiple-mongo-update-operator-in-a-single-statement) that with the shell i can do it like this

```
db.mycollection.update({ "_id": "1234567890" }, 
   {
      "$push" : { "elements": "a new string" }, 
      "$set" : { "last_user": "last user name" }
   }
);
```

but I have no idea how I can build that single update object containing both `$push` and `$set` with java driver . I'm quite sure it's pretty simple and stupid but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`combine`](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/client/model/Updates.html#combine-org.bson.conversions.Bson...-).

```
mycollection.updateOne(filter, combine(addElement,updateLastUser);
```