# How to run a `$set` and `$pull` within a Meteor method?

Tags: meteor, collections

I want to update a collection called `SMUProfiles`, through a method called `classroom.delete`. I want to pull out the `classroom_id` from 2 places inside `SMUProfiles` i.e. one inside `classrooms.owner` which has an array of codes, and the other inside array `classrooms.students`.

I have successfully one the $set part, and now trying to add the $pull, but `$pull` doesn't seem to work.

Can we do the `$set` and `$pull` in such way?

```js
/* Method for deleting Classroom */
'classroom.delete'(classroom_id) {
  if (!this.userId) {
    throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorised');
  }
  Classrooms.remove(classroom_id)
  let classids = Classrooms.find({ owner: this.userId }).fetch().map(function(classrooms){
    return classrooms._id })
  //console.log(classids);
  SMUProfiles.update({
      owner: this.userId,
    }, {
      $set: {
        'classrooms.owner': classids
      },
      $pull: {
        'classrooms.students': classroom_id
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: What exactly defines `does not work`? Any errors or unexpected behavior experienced? If so, what behavior did you expect?

Comment: @Jankapunkt the `$pull` did not pull out the `classroom_id` from a list of array inside `classrooms.students`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to `$set` and `$pull` on the same field in the same update - the two operations conflict; so no, you can't use these operators in this way.

You could easily split this into two:

```
SMUProfiles.update(
  { owner: this.userId },
  { $set: { 'classrooms.owner': classids },
);
SMUProfiles.update(
  { owner: this.userId },
  { $pull: { 'classrooms.students': classroom_id },
);
```

See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9825001/3783510)