# Can I use $pull and update remaining elements in the same array in Mongo/Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema of `Delivery`:

```
const DeliverySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    projectId: { type: String, default: "", trim: true },
    tasks: [{
        timestamp: { type: Date, default: new Date() },
        isAssigned: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        dr1Manager: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        dr2Manager: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        status: { type: String, default: "dr1", trim: true },
        pair: { type: String, default: "", trim: true },
        taskId: { type: String, default: "", trim: true },
        files: [{
            fileName: { type: String, default: "", trim: true },
            path: { type: String, default: "", trim: true },
            isFileApproved: { type: Boolean, default: false },
            isOriginal: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        }],
        instructions: [{
            step: { type: String, default: "dr1", trim: true },
            text: { type: String, default: "", trim: true },
            isChecked: { type: Boolean, default: false }
        }],
    }]
});
```

I'd like to know if I can `$pull` data from `instructions` array and change remaining elements in that array in the same query. I'm trying to do it this way:

```
await Delivery.updateOne(
  { projectId, "tasks.taskId": taskId },
  {
    "tasks.$[i].isAssigned": false,
    "tasks.$[i].status": "dr1",
    "tasks.$[i].dr1Manager": manager,
    $pull: { "tasks.$[i].instructions": { step: "dr2" } },
    "tasks.$[i].files.$[j].isFileApproved": false,
    "tasks.$[i].instructions.$[k].isChecked": false
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      { "i.taskId": taskId },
      { "j.isFileApproved": true },
      { "k.isChecked": true }
    ]
  }
);
```

As a result I get an error:

> Updating the path \'tasks.$[i].instructions\' would create a conflict
>   at \'tasks.$[i].instructions\

So how can I get that done?

Comment: It seems update operators cannot be used for the same field. Here is an old [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9825001/11717458)

Comment: Does it mean that the answer with `bulkWrite` is the most suitable for such cases?

Comment: If it works, yes

Comment: Actually it works great.

Comment: Then you can accept the Daniyal’s answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if that would be suitable, but you can use `bulkWrite`:

```
await Delivery.bulkWrite([
  {
    updateOne: {
      filter: { projectId, "tasks.taskId": taskId },
      update: {
        "tasks.$[i].isAssigned": false,
        "tasks.$[i].status": "dr1",
        "tasks.$[i].dr1Manager": manager,
        $pull: { "tasks.$[i].instructions": { step: "dr2" } },
        "tasks.$[i].files.$[j].isFileApproved": false
      },
      arrayFilters: [{ "i.taskId": taskId }, { "j.isFileApproved": true }]
    }
  },
  {
    updateOne: {
      filter: { projectId, "tasks.taskId": taskId },
      update: {
        "tasks.$[i].instructions.$[k].isChecked": false
      },
      arrayFilters: [{ "i.taskId": taskId }, { "k.isChecked": true }]
    }
  }
]);
```

Here is the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-write-operations-updateonemany)