# Mongoose: is it possible to combine many database calls into one?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've got 4 database operations in 1 API call, is it excessive? Can/should they be combined somehow?

```
// 1) Get the id for the user I want to follow

      const account = await userModel
        .findOne({ 'shared.username': username })
        .exec();
      if (!account) throw new Error('User not found');

// 2) Save the user id I want to follow and my Id into the following collection

      const followed = new followingModel({
        followingId: account.id,
        userId: id,
      } as FollowingModelInterface);
      const saved = await followed.save();

// 3) Increment the number of people I'm following

      const addFollowing = await userModel
      .findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: id },
        {
          $inc: { 'shared.following': 1 },
        },
        {
          new: true,
        }
      )
      .exec();

// 4) Increment the number of people who are following the user i just followed

      const addFoller = await userModel
      .findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: account.id },
        {
          $inc: { 'shared.followers': 1 },
        },
        {
          new: true,
        }
      )
      .exec();
```

It feels like allot of trips to  the database but maybe it's ok I'm not sure?

Maybe 3 and 4 dont need `await` and I can send a response to the front end after 2??

Maybe I'm overthinking it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and fourth operations look like that can be combined like this:

```
  const account = await userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "shared.username": username },
    {
      $inc: { "shared.followers": 1 }
    },
    { new: true }
  );
```

Or you can combine 3 userModel related update by using mongoose [Model.bulkWrite](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite)

Comment: nice find, other than reducing the number of calls to the database I guess it's acceptable to make as many calls as needed, and there is no way of combining them into one?

Comment: @Bill another solution would be using [Model.bulkWrite](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite)

Comment: is this something I should be doing like is it common practice?

Comment: I think bulkWrite would be better in this case.

Comment: @Bill here is [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59286286/11717458) with bulkWrite in case you need.